# Retreive last record inserted

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I want to retrieve the last record of data inserted. I researched and learn't I must use SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(). I have tried and not working. So I have provided my code below

```
  //Inserting into Student Table
            string query = "INSERT INTO student(name) Values('" + txtboxname.Text + "' )";
          // query= "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
            // query += " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
            //Inserting into course table
            string query1 = "INSERT INTO course(title) Values('" + txttitle.Text + "')";
          //  query1 = " SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";

            //Execute Insert Statement queries
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command = new MySqlCommand(query1, con);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //Close and dispose off connections
            command.Dispose();
            con.Close();
```

//Preview page

```
        string query1 = "SELECT (name) FROM student WHERE ID = id"; 
        string query2 = "SELECT (title) FROM course WHERE ID = id";

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query1, con);
        lblname.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        command = new MySqlCommand(query2, con);
        lbltitle.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        con.Close();
```

Comment: What did you get with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`?

Comment: You want to get the primary key value of the last inserted record? Does the table have primary key column as AutoIncrement?

Comment: still returning only the first record from the database

Comment: Yes, the primary keys are all auto incrementing

Comment: As suggested in the answer below you can select Max of the primary key column to get the latest inserted primary key value. Why do you want to select the latest record ID value?

Comment: _primary keys are all auto incrementing_ are there more than one?

Comment: student table has auto increment, course table has auto increment. they're all incrementing in sync

Comment: Once insertion, store the  LAST_INSERT_ID() in a variable, so that you can use that variable in next query.

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: set @last=last_insert_id();

Comment: as per my code, can you demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: sure but can you give an example or sample, like how last_insert_id is not working? like how many records in table and how many records gets inserted (if multiple insert in a single query last_insert_id will be the 1st insert id).

Comment: on line 3 and 7 of my sample code now commented out.

Comment: check my answer hope it solves !!!

Answer (score 0):

if you have set the table id to auto-increment then find the max id from the table that will be your last insert as per my knowledge if it works.

Comment: You need to make your answer more useful with more description and related code snippets.

Comment: I thought about race conditions and it would conflict or return false values if several people are entering into the database at that time

Comment: Yes... It can cause an issue when multiple users are inserting data in the table. Why you want to get the latest value of primary key?

Comment: it's a preview page for data inserted in previous pages for that particular user with that unique id

Answer (score 0):

In your Code change as follows,

line no: 3 `query="set @std_id=last_insert_id();"`

line no: 7 `query1="set @title_id=last_insert_id();"`

**Preview Page:**

```
    string query1 = "SELECT (name) FROM student WHERE ID = query"; 
    string query2 = "SELECT (title) FROM course WHERE ID = query1";
```

Comment: hi, i got the following error "Fatal error encountered during command execution", pointing at line 4 of preview page. I have tried a try catch with the same error

Comment: sorry, so what is id? in your preview page? use the query & query1 from that and use it.

Comment: id in preview page is 'id'. It's still returning the first record, that is if I'm getting what you meant by  'use the query & query1 from that and use it'. can you edit your code to much my sample code?

Comment: just check how to call a variable in another query  in your c# or asp.net, Since i can explain the SQL part.

Comment: the column name in the db is 'id' for both student and course. so i am pointing to that.

Comment: In my point of view it will display all the records in the table.So it is not right.

Comment: as a sample, try commenting the other table query in all and executing only one table at once.

Comment: I tried that earlier, still gve me the same outcome like i will do for multiple  queries